# Inyección de dependencia con datos JSON

Tags: c#, json, unity, inyeccion-de-dependencias

Quiero deserializar un *JSON* y mediante inyección de dependencia se resuelva los datos en la clase correspondiente.

Tengo el siguiente *JSON* para deserializar:

```
{
  "OpenData": {
    "OpenDataRow": [
      {
        "TIPO": "ANUNCIO_LICITACION",
        "IMPORTE": "100",
        "DURACION": "12 MESES",
        "ADJUDICATARIO": "ETXARREN",
        "PRODECIMIENTO_ADJUDICATARIO": ""
      },
      {
        "TIPO": "ANUNCIO_ADJUDICACION",
        "IMPORTE": "100",
        "DURACION": "12 MESES",
        "DESTINATARIO": "ETXARREN",
        "PRODECIMIENTO_ADJUDICATARIO": "",
        "ESTADO": "",
        "PORCENTAJE_TOTAL": ""
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Como se puede ver, hay una serie de datos comunes para ambos tipos además de una tipología especificada.

Tengo dos clases para tratar los distintos tipos, en este caso son adjudicaciones y licitaciones, adjunto las dos clases.

```
public class Licitacion : iAnuncio
{
    public string Tipo { get; set; }
    public double importe { get; set; }
    public string duracion { get; set; }
    public string adjudicatario { get; set; }
    public string procedimiento_Adjudicatario { get; set; }
    public void Tratar()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Se guarda en la tabla  TRATAR");
    }
}

public class Adjudicacion : iAnuncio
{
    public string Tipo { get; set; }
    public double importe { get; set; }
    public string duracion { get; set; }
    public string adjudicatario { get; set; }
    public string procedimiento_Adjudicatario { get; set; }
    public string estado { get; set; }
    public string porcentajeTotal { get; set; }

    public void Tratar()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Se guarda en la tabla  ADJUDICACIONES");
    }
}
```

Como se puede ver ambas tienen un método `Tratar` que tratará los datos de una forma distinta. Ya habréis visto que las clases pertenecen a la interface `iAnuncio`, la cual muestro a continuación:

```
public interface iAnuncio
{
    string Tipo { get; set; }
    double importe { get; set; }
    string duracion { get; set; }
    string adjudicatario { get; set; }
    string procedimiento_Adjudicatario { get; set; }

    void Tratar();
}
```

Para deserializar los datos utilizo las siguientes clases de datos:

```
public class OpenData 
{
    public List<iAnuncio> OpenDataRow { get; set; }

    public void Tratar()
    {
        OpenDataRow.ForEach(r =>
        {
            r.Tratar();
        });
    }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public OpenData OpenData { get; set; }
}
```

y por último el proceso de deserializar el cual se llama desde el botón `btnTratar`:

```
private void btnTratar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RootObject openData =DesSerializar(textBox1.Text.Trim().ToString());
    openData.OpenData.Tratar();
}

private RootObject DesSerializar(string json)
{
    RootObject openData = new RootObject();
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json));

    DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(openData.GetType());
    openData = ser.ReadObject(ms) as RootObject;
    ms.Close();
    return openData;
}
```

Creo que se entiende por el código que es lo que quiero hacer pero básicamente es que al deserializar se resuelva de forma automática a cada clase y recorriendo una lista o de `iAlmacen` para llamar a tratar.

¿Voy por buen camino? ¿Sabéis de algún artículo que hagan algo parecido?

Answer (score 1):

Suponiendo que no puedes cambiar el JSON lo solución sería primero crear está clase para gestionar la deserialización:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public class CustomJsonConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType.Name == "RootObject";
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        JObject json = JObject.Load(reader);
        var rootObject = new RootObject();
        rootObject.OpenData = new OpenData();
        rootObject.OpenData.OpenDataRow = new List<iAnuncio>();
        foreach(var row in json["OpenData"]["OpenDataRow"])
        {
            if (row["ESTADO"] != null)
                rootObject.OpenData.OpenDataRow.Add(row.ToObject<Adjudicacion>(serializer));
            else
                rootObject.OpenData.OpenDataRow.Add(row.ToObject<Licitacion>(serializer));
        }
        return rootObject;
    }

    public override bool CanWrite
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Y luego cambiar tu función para deserializar por está:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

private static RootObject DesSerializar(string json)
{
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json, new CustomJsonConverter());
}
```